# SSRS or Crystal Reports with QuickBooks (QBW) File?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, birt, quickbooks

Is there a way to export QuickBooks data from a QBW file to generate custom reports using SSRS or Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few more QuickBooks data bridges:

1. [QODBC](http://qodbc.com/default.htm)
2. [RSSBus](http://www.rssbus.com/ado/quickbooks/)
3. [OpenSync](http://www.synergration.com/software/opensync/)